# Using a SqlServer sql query, how to tell if integer column is odd or even?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a simple column definition for a primary key and I'm wanting to add to my where clause something that evaluates true when the value is odd.  My column definition is simply this:

```
Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
```

and I'm wanting something like

```
SELECT Id FROM Attendees Where Id is Odd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Where id % 2 = 1
```

The percent operator in SQL is a modulus operator, basically returning the remainder of the division.

Comment: Just wondering why someone would anonymously vote this question down.  is it too simple a question for them and everyone should know the answer?  Are there SO moderators that remove in appropriate down votes? <hurtfeelings/>. I'm guessing someone will remove this comment but not the downvote.